# How to read last n lines in a Text file in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, text-files

I have a Text file and it has lot of lines How can i get last 'n' number of lines from the text file? and Can we give Numbers in the text file for each file How can we get it.

Comment: You mean you wanna only last line ?

Comment: Not Exactly last line But last 100 lines..

Comment: Try to implement my answer. I Hope you will get your answer....

Answer (score 4):

You could use `NSFileHandle`, `seekToEndOfFile` and then work backwards from the `offsetInFile` using `seekToFileOffset:` and `readDataOfLength:` scanning the data read each time for carriage returns and counting them until you get to the required number. As you go you can build up the text after each scan.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this one:

```
    NSString* textFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                   pathForResource:@"fileName" ofType:@"txt"];

    NSString* fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile: textFile 
           encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding error: nil];
```

Separate by new line

```
    NSArray* allLinedStrings = 
          [fileContents componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
          [NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
```

Here you can get your last 100 objects

```
    NSString* oneLineStr;
    for (int i = allLinedStrings.count - 100; i < allLinedStrings.count; i++)
    {
        oneLineStr = [allLinedStrings objectAtIndex: i];
        NSLog@("New Line %@", oneLineStr);
    }
```

Comment: What if the file size is 10 MB? Would you wait several seconds for something that can be done in several milliseconds?

Comment: Yes ofcourse it will wait and if you good solution then let me know plz ?

Answer (score 0):

One way is putting \n to separate your different lines in the text file. Then

```
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"filename" 
                                                 ofType:@"txt"];
NSString* content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path
                                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                 error:NULL];
NSArray* lines = [content componentsSeparatedByString: @"\n"];
```

Then you can take the last few elements in the array.

Hope this helps..